# How do I package my source code on a GitHub repo for a PPA?

Tags: ppa

I am trying to make a PPA to run a custom version of open5gs on POWDER testbed.
The source code will be a GitHub repo so how do I include the source code in my package? I believe I need to make .deb package?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For PPA you need to host it in [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net/). Alternatively, you can host it in GitHub, and mirror it in Launchpad. *how do I include the source code in my package* -- This is unclear. *I believe I need to make .deb package* -- Launchpad does that for you.

Comment: Note that you first need to create a debian source (which can be compiled into .deb in your computer).

Comment: "how do I include the source code in my package -- This is unclear" I mean to say that the code I'm trying to package is a GitHub repo and has many files so I am unsure if I need to do something different. How does one create a debian source?

Comment: *How does one create a debian source?* -- It is [complicated](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/start.en.html). The easiest way is to see the source code structure of a similar app (written in the same programming language). Without more details we really cannot help. Can you post a link to the GitHub repo, so that someone may be able to add more information?

Comment: https://github.com/open5gs/open5gs here is the repo. I am aware open5gs already has an active PPA but I am just using this repo as a placeholder as my team's code will take some time to be finished but the repo would be very similar to this one. I just need to do the process of packaging and creating a PPA once.

Comment: This project is already in debian source format. Import it into Launchpad (register it if already not), and mirror the code from GitHub. Then there would be an option for creating a packaging recipe (go with the default options). Once that is done, there would be an option to build it into a PPA. If you get stuck, ask a new question for each of them.

Comment: By debian source format, do you mean the "debian" folder? And if I change some of the code later, would I be able to follow the same steps or would I have to manually change to debian source format?

Comment: Yes, a properly configured `debian/` folder turns it into a "debian source". After changing the code, you only need to update the changelog in the debian source folder (with the command `dch`). Once you have created the PPA, after changing the source you only need to build it again in Launchpad (no need to repeat the other steps).

Comment: Okay thank you so much! You have been very helpful!